# How to append a value coming from oneActivity on Another Activity in android

Tags: android, append, android-intent, bundle, pixel

i have two Activity in this i take pixels of image from one activity and  pass that value to the next activity and store it in text view As String.AND When i take the next pixel value and pass to the second activity  the earlier  value in the text View is replaced by the new pixel value.now what i need is that i want to append the current value with previous value .i will show you my code for more specification

///Selectpassword.java(where i get the piels of images)

```
public class Selectpassword extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
Bitmap overlay;      
Paint pTouch;
int X = -100;
int Y = -100;
Canvas c2;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent mIntent = getIntent();
    int intValue = mIntent.getIntExtra("intVariableName", 0);
    System.out.println("+++++++++++++++++++++"+intValue);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),intValue);
    Bitmap mBitmapover = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), intValue);
    overlay = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),intValue).copy(Config.ARGB_8888, true);  
    c2 = new Canvas(overlay);

    pTouch = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);         
  //  pTouch.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.TARGET); 
    pTouch.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    pTouch.setMaskFilter(new BlurMaskFilter(15, Blur.NORMAL));
    setContentView(new BitMapView(this, mBitmap,mBitmapover));
}

class BitMapView extends View {
    Bitmap mBitmap = null;
    Bitmap mBitmapover = null;

    public BitMapView(Context context, Bitmap bm, Bitmap bmover) {
    super(context);
    mBitmap = bm;
    mBitmapover = bmover;
    }
     @Override
     public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

         switch (ev.getAction()) {

             case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {

                 X = (int) ev.getX();
                 Y = (int) ev.getY();


                 System.out.println("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"+X);
                 System.out.println("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"+Y);
                 invalidate();
                 Intent intent = new Intent(Selectpassword.this,Catogry.class); 
                 intent.putExtra("intVariableName", X);//i put the value of the pixels
                // intent.putExtra("intVariableName", Y);
                 startActivity(intent);

                 break;
             }

             case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {

                     X = (int) ev.getX();
                     Y = (int) ev.getY();
                     invalidate();
                     break;

             }           

             case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                 break;

         }
         return true;
     }


    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // called when view is drawn
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setFilterBitmap(true);


    //draw background
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, null);
    //copy the default overlay into temporary overlay and punch a hole in it                          
    c2.drawBitmap(mBitmapover, 0, 0, null); //exclude this line to show all as you draw
    c2.drawCircle(X, Y, 80, pTouch);
    //draw the overlay over the background  
    canvas.drawBitmap(overlay, 0, 0, null);
    }
}

  }
```

//Catogry.java(Where i append the pixels in text view)

```
public class Catogry extends Activity {

 LinearLayout background;
 Spinner spinnerColor;
 TextView password;

 private static final String[] colorf =
  { "SELECT ANY FIELD","ANIMAL",  
  "BIRDS",
  "BABYS",
  };
 private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.catogry);



    spinnerColor = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.colorspinner);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
      android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, colorf);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(
      android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerColor.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinnerColor.setSelection(0);
    Intent mIntent = getIntent();
    int passwords = mIntent.getIntExtra("intVariableName", 0);//getting the pixel and convent the values to string
    password=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.appenpass);//text view
  // password.setText(Integer.toString(passwords));
    password.append(Integer.toString(passwords));//appending the values
    spinnerColor.setOnItemSelectedListener(
      new Spinner.OnItemSelectedListener(){

  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  // setBackgroundColor(spinnerColor.getSelectedItem().toString());

  switch(position){
   case 0:

   break;
   case 1:
   //call second class
       Intent animal=new Intent(Catogry.this,Animals.class);
       startActivity(animal);

   break;
   case 2:
   //call third class
       Intent bird=new Intent(Catogry.this,Birds.class);
       startActivity(bird);
   break;
   case 3:
       //call third class
           Intent baby=new Intent(Catogry.this,Babys.class);
           startActivity(baby);
       break;

   default:
   break;
       }
  }


  public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }});
   }



 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no one answer this question any way i find it myself

I have pass the bundle from one page to another that means.i get the pixel from the canvas page and pass it to the next activity from there the value pass from that page to canvas page  where i do

> String canvas="";
>   canvas=canvas+X;(THe X is an integer where i had converted the X in to a String )
>   and pass the canvas values so that i have successfully append my value.